# jquery not printing the image in IE 6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

```
if(count > 0){
for(var i= parseInt(start); i < parseInt(count); i++)
{

link ='<a href="/diabetes/ropimages/origpicdisplay.php?pid='+pid+'&rid='+i+'" target="_blank"><img src="/diabetes/ropimages/thumbpicdisplay.php?pid='+pid+'&rid='+i+'"/><a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';

if(i > start){ $("#content1").append(link);}

else{ $("#content1").empty().html(link);}
}
}
```

i use code like this. it does print images in FF but not in IE6 any solutions for this ?

Comment: Not sure but declare your variable with `var`: `var link = <a href...`

Comment: Can you provide more code or even better - a live page?

Comment: You should quote your `&`s to `&amp;`. Since jQuery inserts the HTML without doing that for you, you end up with invalid HTML, and that could perhaps confuse IE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `$(document).ready`, as far as I remember it has some issues with IE6, so try to put it at the bottom.

Comment: i am getting rest of data ,but only image displaying is problem